# How to look for patterns in numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, midi

Given any array of numbers, similar in nature to the following:

```
[48, 60, 64, 67, 72]
```

I want to be able to evaluate this(or any) series of numbers and look for musically meaningful patterns, and I'm not sure how to start going about it.

For example, if I subtract 48 from every number I would get this:

```
[0, 12, 16, 19, 24]
```

...one will notice that the 1st, 2nd and 5th numbers are 12 apart from each other, which is a meaningful pattern in music, as 12 steps is one octave. This is one of the things I would want to be able to figure out by just looking at the numbers.

Now, if I take the middle three numbers and subtract 12 from each one I get:

```
[0, 4, 7]
```

...which is the numerical pattern of steps on a keyboard that would create a Major Triad, which is another example of something I would want to be able to evaluate from a series of numbers.

So, in the end, the original series of numbers:

```
[48, 60, 64, 67, 72]
```

...represents the following musical notes:

```
[`C2`, `C3`, `E3`, `G3`, `C4`]
```

...which is a C Major Triad `C3`, `E3`, `G3` with the root doubled down one octave `C2` and doubled up one octave `C4` as well.

What I want to do is write some code that takes in any series of midi message numbers, like the example above, evaluates them, then tells the user what musical entity they have played, including inversions, doublings, other possible interpretations, etc...

There would be a database/dictionary/object/array/data-thing of some type that contains many different patterns, then the code would compare the incoming numbers to this set of patterns to find the correct one(s)...

Not looking for code answers as much as an idea as to how to go about even getting started with such a thing in javascript, as this would be for the web...

I just don't really have any idea how to start going about this, but any thoughts or examples or resources that could point me in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Thanks! XD

Comment: I am not great at music theory, so I can't answer this question, but I just gotta say this is super awesome! Good luck))

Comment: Find min value. Subtract so that you have 0-based numbers. Sort. Find in the collection of presets. Sounds like a basic stuff.